# Failure while starting rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activesupport

While running the command rails server, I am getting following exception

```
[2016-06-26 13:21:57] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-06-26 13:21:57] INFO  ruby 2.1.3 (2014-09-19) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
[2016-06-26 13:21:57] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2471 port=3000
[2016-06-26 13:22:08] ERROR LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support/security_utils
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/base.rb:206:in `<class:Base>'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/base.rb:171:in `<module:ActionController>'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_controller/base.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:32:in `ext'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:16:in `match?'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-3.2.17/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:77:in `call'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/engine.rb:484:in `call'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/application.rb:231:in `call'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/railties-3.2.17/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
        /usr/lib64/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
[2016-06-26 13:22:08] ERROR LoadError: cannot load such file -- active_support/security_utils
        /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:
```

My gem file looks like this
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/

```
  specs:
    actionmailer (3.2.17)
      actionpack (= 3.2.17)
      mail (~> 2.5.4)
    actionpack (3.2.17)
      activemodel (= 3.2.17)
      activesupport (= 3.2.17)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      journey (~> 1.0.4)
      rack (~> 1.4.5)
      rack-cache (~> 1.2)
      rack-test (~> 0.6.1)
      sprockets (~> 2.2.1)
    activemodel (3.2.17)
      activesupport (= 3.2.17)
      builder (~> 3.0.0)
    activerecord (3.2.17)
      activemodel (= 3.2.17)
      activesupport (= 3.2.17)
      arel (~> 3.0.2)
      tzinfo (~> 0.3.29)
    activeresource (3.2.17)
      activemodel (= 3.2.17)
      activesupport (= 3.2.17)
    activesupport (3.2.17)
      i18n (~> 0.6, >= 0.6.4)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
    arel (3.0.3)
    builder (3.0.4)
    coffee-rails (3.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.10.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    hike (1.2.3)
    i18n (0.7.0)
    journey (1.0.4)
    jquery-rails (3.1.4)
      railties (>= 3.0, < 5.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    json (1.8.3)
    mail (2.5.4)
      mime-types (~> 1.16)
      treetop (~> 1.4.8)
    mime-types (1.25.1)
    multi_json (1.12.1)
    polyglot (0.3.5)
    rack (1.4.7)
    rack-cache (1.6.1)
      rack (>= 0.4)
    rack-ssl (1.3.4)
      rack
    rack-test (0.6.3)
      rack (>= 1.0)
    rails (3.2.17)
      actionmailer (= 3.2.17)
      actionpack (= 3.2.17)
      activerecord (= 3.2.17)
      activeresource (= 3.2.17)
      activesupport (= 3.2.17)
      bundler (~> 1.0)
      railties (= 3.2.17)
    railties (3.2.17)
      actionpack (= 3.2.17)
      activesupport (= 3.2.17)
      rack-ssl (~> 1.3.2)
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      rdoc (~> 3.4)
      thor (>= 0.14.6, < 2.0)
    rake (11.2.2)
    rdoc (3.12.2)
      json (~> 1.4)
    sass (3.4.22)
    sass-rails (3.2.6)
      railties (~> 3.2.0)
      sass (>= 3.1.10)
      tilt (~> 1.3)
    sprockets (2.2.3)
      hike (~> 1.2)
      multi_json (~> 1.0)
      rack (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 1.1, != 1.3.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.11)
    thor (0.19.1)
    tilt (1.4.1)
    treetop (1.4.15)
      polyglot
      polyglot (>= 0.3.1)
    tzinfo (0.3.50)
    uglifier (3.0.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  coffee-rails (~> 3.2.1)
  jquery-rails
  rails (= 3.2.17)
  sass-rails (~> 3.2.3)
  sqlite3
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)

BUNDLED WITH
   1.12.5
```

ActiveSupport is already present /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.17

Ruby version ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-linux-gnu]

Comment: Delete your Gemfile.lock file and try to run bundle update and then bundle install again. I hope it works for you.

Comment: It didn't work. Again same problem. I have configured ruby and rails yesterday only, so version mismatch might not be there.

Comment: please make sure that you have a node js runtime globally installed .

Comment: Nodejs-devel was not present. Added it. Still same problem